# How do I create a select box using two tables with a relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to create a select box that shows all my `ejecutive_name` and `last_name` from my table Ejecutives in my Policies view,but i need to create a search button to get parameters from Ejecutives that i selected

My models have a relationship:

```
class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
  unloadable
  belongs_to :ejecutive
  has_many :policy 
end

class Ejecutive < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :policies
end
```

My tables have a relationship by `ejecutive_id`:

```
class CreateEjecutives < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
   create_table :ejecutives do |t|
     t.string :name,:null=>false
     t.string :lastname1,:null=>false
     t.timestamps
   end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :ejecutives
  end
end

class CreatePolicies < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def self.up
   create_table :policies do |t|
     t.string :num_policy, :null=>false
     t.integer :ejecutive_id
     t.timestamps
   end
 end

 def self.down
  drop_table :policies
 end
end
```

This is my controller:

```
class PolicyManagement::PolicyController < ApplicationController
   @ejecutives = Ejecutive.find(:all)
   @policies = Policy.find(:all)
end
```

This is my view:

```
 Select Ejecutive:
 %= select_tag 'ejecutives',"<option value=\"\">Seleccione</option>"+options_for_select(@ejecutives.collect {|t| [t.name.to_s+" "+t.lastname1.to_s,t.id]})%>


 Results
  <% @policies.each do |policy| %>
  <p> <%= policy.num_policy%> </p>
  <p> <%= policy.ejecutive.name %> </p>
  <p> <%= policy.ejecutive.last_name %> </p>
  <% end %>
```

I tried this

```
<% form_tag :controller=>"policy_management/policy",:action =>"generate_print_ejecutive_comercial", :method => 'get' do %>
  <p>
  <%= text_field_tag :search,params[:search] %>
  <%= select_tag "Ejecutives", options_from_collection_for_select(@ejecutives, "id", "name") %>
   #Here i in select_tag "ejecutives" need to add searh params..
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

I'm using Rails 2.3.5.

Does somebody know about this problem? I'd really appreciate help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, you want the policies for a selected ejecutive, you can do this by saying Ejecutive.find().policies. If want a search button, put your select box in a form tag and post it. In the controller action, you will get the selected id, with which you can execute the line i mentioned above.Hope this helps.

Comment: Hope this helps http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPor5ErX_90 (precisely, after 3.00 minutes into the video). Also the suggested videos after this by youtube were also related to your question.